# Some links are not clickable in Internet Explorer 6, why?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I'm having problem with IE 6 (what a surprise : D)

On [this site](http://balatonnet.com/cats/lstSubCat/13), in the content, I cannot click on the first few links. But after a few items, the links are working fine.

This problem appears if I load a page with ajax from the menu.

I couldn't figure out the problem, has anybody seen something like this before?

The HTML code is:

```html
<div id="cont" style="display: block;">
    <div class="localHeader">
        <span> Szállás &gt; Magánszállás </span>
    </div>
    <div class="subList">
        <div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img style="width: 200px;" src="/up/21/480_98_szarka2_255.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="productName">
                    <a title="Szarka család" href="/cats/showItem/21" rel="history"> Szarka család </a>
                </div>
                <div class="productDatas">
                    <a href="mailto:kato55@freemail.hu"> kato55@freemail.hu </a>
                    <br>
                    <a title="Szarka család" href=""></a>
                    <br>
                    +36 84 314 062
                </div>
                <div class="productText"></div>
                <a title="Szarka család" href="/cats/showItem/21" rel="history" class="moreButton"> Részletek </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course the `.productContainer` is repeating in the `.subList`.

Thanks.

Comment: Post some code please to help identify the issue.

Comment: There is a link in the question, I'm talking about that site

Comment: Yes, I know. But we would like to see how the links are being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have explicitly set overflow:auto on .productContainer.  If that doesn't work, try Googling "clearfix" and see if that doesn't fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that your HTML validates against the DocType you're using, at the moment it doesn't and this can effect how browsers render parts of the page.

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbalatonnet.com%2Fcats%2FlstSubCat%2F13